# I cannot set breakpoints - Captions showing unbound breakpoint

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

On my Angular application, I get `unbound breakpoint` captions above my breakpoints after starting the debugger.

It used to work "before".

The versions:

```
VSCode   1.66.2
Node     v16.14.2
Angular  ~13.3.1
Chrome   100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

How I start Chrome:

```
google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

I can see the listening port:

```
07:31 $ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN | grep 9222
chrome     2476        stephane  107u  IPv4  45590      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9222 (LISTEN)
```

My `launch.json` file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "[localhost] Attach to Chrome",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9222,
        "trace": true,
        "url": "http://localhost:4200/*",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    },
  ]
}
```

With trace enabled, the gzip log file generated, I [could upload](https://microsoft.github.io/vscode-pwa-analyzer/index.html) this archive file and the log showed no FATAL nor ERROR.